# How to verify a number translator?

Tags: python

I do have a nice piece of software code here (written in Python) which translates a given English number – e.g., two thousand three hundred forty five – into the Arabic number – 2345 – and then in its German equal – zweitausenddreihundertfünfundvierzig.

One speciality of the German language is that it “twists” the tens and the singles, i.e., word-by-word translated, the number 2345 reads in German: two-thousand three-hundred five and forty.

The code does that perfectly for any number I entered. Back and forth, from English to German, from German to English.

Yet: How to *test* systematically that it works correctly for any number?

If the code processes a finite set of values, this would be easy, as I could simply could test all values against a table of the correct (= expected) answers/results.

How to test – at least, partly, – the code? Any idea will be appreciated :-)

Comment: Any *code* you write might have a bug which might lead to false positives. To be *sure* you simply want a table of as many hardcoded, human-vetted English-German pairs as possible.

Comment: I want to point out that if you do what a table of all hardcoded values to test on, then it kind of defies the purpose of you code since you could simply use the table.

Comment: Take advantage of the fact that `f(x*100 + y) == f(x*100) + f(y)` for `0 <= x, y < 100`.

Comment: One good testing scenario is `ASSERT_EQ(Int2German(someIntNumber), Englith2German(German2English(Int2German(someIntNumber))))`

Comment: This is more of a linguistics question. In order to "test systematically" the correctness of your system you need to systematically know all the possible "twists" and corner cases that you may come across. Algorithmically, you have no guarantees that ten million and one will follow a different rule than previous numbers, but you know, linguistically, that doesn't happen. So sadly, like in most cases, the solution is that you just need to have enough knowledge about the domain of the problem (English and German numbers) to come up with a sufficient set of test cases.

Answer (score 4):

Test the small cases. Test the edge cases. Test a few things in between. Testing an infinite number of values is not possible, but systematically checking all plausible failure points and adding tests as bugs are observed will ensure that going forward your library never regresses in quality.

In particular, have a few tests for negatives (if your library handles those), have tests for every number from 0-101 (these being the most variable in most languages), have all of the important break-points (999, 1000, 1001, 9999, 10000, 10001, etc...), and have a few things in between.

As far as how to actually do that systematically, `unittest` is the testing module that comes with Python. Many people prefer `nose.py` or `py.test` for testing as well. There are plenty of in-depth tutorials on how to use any of those.

As @FredLarson just mentioned, using a code coverage tool like `coverage.py` is a good way to ensure that your tests are all running properly.

Comment: I'd use a [coverage tool](http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) as well to make sure all the functionality is tested.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it is to convert a type sensitive case of an fraction before operation, so if some language has peculiar "wording" for specific sets of decimal, you can have a test case that is part of an number of infinite set.

Since every living language that I know uses decimal system, we have a nice rule about it, the 100, 1000 and etc are most stable digits for pronounciation , since they are always plural in form. So singular forms are often based up to base 10 (we have that much fingers ) by language barrier, for example in my native language after number 5 all numbers become plural because 5 is one whole hand and every number afterwards needs second hand to count it on. This plural/singular form in then transcribed into linguistics, since 4321 would be written as 4320 and 1 form. I am guessing that most of other languages have some similar elements to their linguistics. So you generally need to check first 2 digits, the 1 place and 10 place to verify your translator.

So in the number of *n* by converting it to int and testing it by `n//10+n//1` in that specific translator and then doing simple comparison of strings you could be able to generate pretty good verification for most of the languages. Then it is just inputting the exceptions for different language groups.

But I must say this is up most based on logic , I am not a linguist or anything. I hope this helped.